# How to add image to a Border object in WP7

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, border

In my windows phone app, I have a rectangular `Border`. I want to add image in the center of the border. How to do that using `C#` ?

**Edit**
This code is not displaying any image. Any idea why ?

```
Border b = (Border)FindName("border"+nom);
if (move == 1)
{
   var bi = new BitmapImage
   {
       UriSource = new Uri("/Images/smiley1.png", UriKind.Relative)
   };
   b.Child = new Image { Source = bi };
}
```

**Edit 2**
Apparently, correct syntax is `UriSource = new Uri("/BoxIt;component/Images/smiley1.png", UriKind.Relative)`
This solves the problem :)

Comment: kindly write the reason behind the negative vote

Comment: A negative vote here likely means that the person felt that you did not do much research or expend enough effort.  If you post some code and show us how far you have come, you will be more likely to get help.

Comment: @davehale23 the reason i did not add any code is that i am sure it will be just one line of code, but i am not able to figure out how.

Comment: I wasn't the down voter, I'm just speculating based on your original question.  The down voter SHOULD have said why in a comment since you are new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an *Image* can be adeed to a *Border* using following code:

```
// Assume you have a border named Border1
Border1.Child = new Image() { /* ... */ };
```

Note: I do not recommend this. *DataTemplates* with *Data binding* or *TemplatedControls* should be used when possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straight forward. You could have done a plain search.
Anyways here's the solution you are looking for -

In XAML -

```
<Border BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" BorderBrush="#FF000000" >

<Image x:Name="imgMainImage"  Visibility="Visible" Height="205" Width="180" />

</Border>
```

Comment: could you please tell me how to do that in c#

Comment: @decyclone this is the solution, kindly write is down so that i can mark it, thanks